# Codimension zero subgroup of a compact Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, compactness

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $H$ a compact Lie subgroup, $g\in G$, and suppose $g^{-1}Hg\subset H$. In p.45 of Bredon's book *Introduction to Compact Transformation Groups*, it is then asserted that $g^{-1}Hg=H$ by the following reason: $g^{-1}Hg$ has the same dimension and number of components as does $H$. I can see that $g^{-1}Hg$ has the same dimension and number of components as does $H$, but how does this imply that $g^{-1}Hg=H$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of a compact Lie groups are such that $H_1$ is a subgroup of $H_2$, then $\dim H_1<\dim H_2$ or $H_1$ has less components of $H_2$. To see why, suppose that $\dim H_1=\dim H_2$. The component $H_1^0$ of $e_G$ in $H_1$ is connected and therefore it's a subset of the component $H_2^0$ of $e_G$ in $H_2$. But two Lie connected Lie groups of the same dimension and such that one of them is a subgroup of the other one must be identical (this follows from the fact that the image of the exponential map is a neighborhood of $e_G$ and from the fact that every connected Lie group is spanned by every neighborhood of $e_G$). So, $H_1^0=H_2^0$. And, since $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the same number of components (which is a natural number, since $G$ is compact), it follows that $H_1=H_2$.